# How to solve this differential equation? Error (NSolve :: ifun)

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

When I solve the differential equation I get an error:

**error:**
Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

**code of the differential equation:**

```
DSolve[{(H'[x])^2 - ((1 + 6 H[x]^2)^2 H[x]^2)/(
 6 (1 + 18 H[x]^2)) + ((1 + 6 H[x]^2)^2 E^-x)/(
 18 (1 + 18 H[x]^2)) == 0, H[0] == 10^(1)}, H, x] // FullSimplify
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NDSolve rather than DSolve. DSolve looking for an analytical solution and it may not exist.
NDSolve requires range $ {xmin, xmax} &, in adition

```
 NDSolve[{(H'[x])^2 - ((1 + 6 H[x]^2)^2 H[x]^2)/(6 (1 +18 H[x]^2)) + 
((1 + 6 H[x]^2)^2 E^-x)/(18 (1 + 18 H[x]^2)) == 0, H[0] == 10^(1)}, H, {x, 0, 0.1}]
```

Comment: I think so, but the idea was to find an analytical solution. Thanks, I really appreciate.